# Custom Account Hierarchy visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, account

I'm trying to create a VF page to display Account hierarchy and the relative opportunities.

**Controller**

```
public class AccountHierarchyCtrl{

    public MyAccount parentAcc {get;set;}
    public Map<Id, List<Account>> childrenPerParent {get;set;}
    public Account accnt {get;set;}

    public class MyAccount {


      public Account acc {get;set;}
      public List<Opportunity> optyList {get;set;}
      public List<MyAccount> children {get;set;}

    public MyAccount(Account acc) {
        this.acc = acc;
        optyList = new List<Opportunity>();
        children = new List<MyAccount>();
    }

    public Boolean addChild(Id parentId, Account child) {
        if(acc.Id == parentId) {
            children.add(new MyAccount(child));
            return true;
        } else {
            Boolean result = false;
            Integer i = 0;
            do {
                MyAccount myacc = children[i];
                result = myacc.addChild(parentId, child);
                i++;
            } while(!result && i < children.size());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Set<Id> getChildrenId() {
        Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(MyAccount myacc : children) {
            accIds.add(myacc.acc.Id);
            accIds.addAll(myacc.getChildrenId());
        }
        return accIds;
    }

    public List<MyAccount> getChildrenList() {
        List<MyAccount> childrenList = new List<MyAccount>();
        childrenList.addAll(children);
        for(MyAccount myacc : children) {
            childrenList.addAll(myacc.getChildrenList());
        }
        return childrenList;
    }

    public Boolean addOpty(Id accId, Opportunity opty) {
        if(acc.Id == accId) {
            optyList.add(opty);
            return true;
        } else {
            Boolean result = false;
            Integer i = 0;
            do {
                MyAccount myacc = children[i];
                result = myacc.addOpty(accId, opty);
                i++;
            } while(!result && i < children.size());
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public AccountHierarchyCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController Ctrl){
    this.accnt = (Account)Ctrl.getRecord();

    for(Account acc : [SELECT ParentId, recordtype.name, BillingCity, BillingCountry FROM Account WHERE ParentId != null]) {
    if(childrenPerParent.get(acc.ParentId) == null)
        childrenPerParent.put(acc.ParentId, new List<Account>());
    childrenPerParent.get(acc.ParentId).add(acc);
    }

    parentAcc =new MyAccount(accnt);
    getChildren(accnt.Id);

    Set<Id> accIds = parentAcc.getChildrenId();
    accIds.add(accnt.Id);

    for(Opportunity opty : [SELECT AccountId, Name, Opportunity_Code__c, Amount,   StageName FROM Opportunity 
    WHERE AccountId IN :accIds 
    AND (Recordtype.developername='Child_Opportunity' OR    Recordtype.developername='Child_Opportunity') 
    AND (StageName='Draft - Low' OR StageName='Bid Project - Medium'OR StageName='Approved Project - High' OR StageName='Awarded awaiting implement. - Forecast') ]) {
    parentAcc.addOpty(opty.AccountId, opty);
    }

    List<MyAccount> myAccList = new List<MyAccount>();
    myAccList.add(parentAcc);
    myAccList.addAll(parentAcc.getChildrenList());

    } 



    public void getChildren(Id accId) {
    if(childrenPerParent.get(accId) != null) {
        for(Account a : childrenPerParent.get(accId)) {
            parentAcc.addChild(accId, a);
            getChildren(a.Id);
        }
    }




     } 
}
```

Now I'm trying to create my visualfroce page, but I can't access to my controller Lists. I get this error:

> Error: Unknown property 'AccountStandardController.children'

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountHierarchyCtrl">

     <apex:pageBlock title="{!Account.Name}" >
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!children}"  var="lines" id="theTable" >

     <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" style="align: center;">
                 <apex:outputField value="{!lines.Account.Name}" style="width: 150px;"/>
            </apex:column> 

         <apex:column headerValue="RecordType" style="align: center;">
                 <apex:outputField value="{!lines.Account.Recordtype.Name}" style="width: 150px;"/>
            </apex:column> 

        <apex:column headerValue="Country" style="align: center;">
                 <apex:outputField value="{!Account.BillingCountry}" style="width: 150px;"/>
            </apex:column> 

   <apex:column headerValue="City" style="align: center;">
                 <apex:outputField value="{!lines.Account.BillingCity}" style="width: 150px;"/>
            </apex:column>                     
    <apex:column headerValue="Opportunity" style="align: center;">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!optyList}" var="l">
    <apex:column headerValue="City" style="align: center;">
                 <apex:outputField value="{!l.acc.Name}" style="width: 150px;"/>
            </apex:column>  
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageblockTable>

</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `children` is an attribute of the `MyAccount` class.  You're referencing it as if it's an attribute of the controller itself.  In your PageBlockTable your value should be `{!parentAcc.children}`.